# How do I kill my own player by pressing a key on my keyboard? (Roblox)

Tags: lua, roblox

As the title suggests, I'm trying to kill my own character in roblox by pressing a button on my keyboard. I've tried `Humanoid.Health = 0`, and also `player.Character.Head:remove()`, but they don't work! My current solution is this:

```
local UserInputService = game:GetService("UserInputService")

local resetStand = IsKeyDown(Enum.KeyCode.Semicolon)

if IsKeyDown(Enum.KeyCode.Semicolon) = true then
    player.Character.Head:remove()
end
```

Answer (score 1):

[IsKeyDown()](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/function/UserInputService/IsKeyDown) is a function which tells you whether or not a key is held **at the moment**. This means it will only check once when the script starts.

What you're looking for is a [keyboard event](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/event/UserInputService/InputBegan). This triggers whenever an input (keyboard, mouse, etc) is triggered. All you have to do is check if the **input** is your key:

```lua
local UIS = game:GetService("UserInputService")

UIS.InputBegan:Connect(function(input, isTyping)
    if not isTyping then --dont wanna acciedentally trigger when player is typing in chat
        if input.KeyCode == Enum.KeyCode.Semicolon then --check if input was a semicolon
            local char = game.Players.LocalPlayer.Character
            char:BreakJoints() --break joints (oof)
        end
    end
end)
```

Make sure the script is a local script. It works for me when I insert it into **StarterPlayerScripts** but there are a number of other places that work as well.